# How to pass value to previous html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page with a textbox. On clicking the textbox, a pop-up shows up and upon clicking the OK button the pop-up has to close and the textbox in the first html page has to be filled with value given in the second HTML.
I tried something like this,

**one.html**

```
    <form name="form1" >
          <input type="text" name="source" onclick="window.open('second.html')" />
    </form>
```

**second.html**

```
  <input type="button" onclick="{document.form1.source.value='hello';window.close()}" />
```

Comment: I think we are missing some code...

Comment: @BvdVen: edited, there was some problem with newlines :)

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice

Comment: From a purely design standpoint, why don't you use a JS popup in the same window rather than opening a new one (which is kind of annoying to be honest)?

Answer (score 2):

in your first.html

```
<form name="form1" >
         <input type="text" id="txt1" name="source" onclick="window.open('second.html')" />
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function setvalue(args)
  {
    document.getElementByid('txt1').value=args;
  }
</script>
```

second.html

```
  <input type="button" onclick="settoparent()" />
<script type="javascript">
  function settoparent()
   {
    if(window.opener.setvalue!=undefined)
     {
      setvalue("textboxvaluefromHTML2");
     }
   window.close()
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use

```
window.opener.$("#yourtextfieldid").val(value);
```

to achieve this

In Your vanila JS

```
window.opener.document.yourelementID.fieldname.value="Any value";
```

Comment: This implies using JQuery though, which apparently he is not

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara: Javascript IS NOT JQuery. JQuery is a library written in Javascript.

Comment: we Hardly see vanila javascript , and he is speaking about popups

Comment: What might be the best way to do this @nico , definately he cant use vanila JS to do this

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara: JQuery is not some magical thing, it has been written in JS, so anything you write in JQuery can be rewritten in JS. For instance `$("#yourtextfield")` is equal to `document.getElementById("yourtextfield")`. By the way, note that [annoying] popup windows existed way before anyone even thought of writing JQuery.

Comment: It might be possible I agree , It is the Op's choice of accepting or confirming what ever he is using , why you and I has to argue here , I assumed and gave an answer for his problem , let him comment and say what is the issue why you are talking about this @DannyBeckett

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara 1) It's tagged Javascript, not JQuery; 2) Your vanilla JS code is completely wrong.

Comment: `document.yourelementID.fieldname` should just by `document.getElemenById("yourelementID")` what is fieldname?

Comment: @DannyBeckett You have only told above that Jquery is internally using javascript and if that was the case how can you conclude that tagging is perfect javascript is a generic tag there I can pick many questions in this stack overflow which has both javascript and jquery tag

Comment: @Scott field name is the name in the form

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara Face it it's not a jQuery question. Stop trying to fight, the comments are for constructive comments.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara I see no mention of `fieldname` in the form. So if you are referencing the form it's called `form1` But you still don't need too. You have referenced the element already, fieldname is not required.