# Pass data from child window to parent window in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I tried to pass data from child window to parent window using javascript but parent.returnvalue is not working in chrome. Is there any alternative of parent.returnvalue??

**CODE**

```
      var txtfolioID = document.getElementById('<%= txtfolioID.ClientID %>');
      var txtfolioName = document.getElementById('<%= txtfolioName.ClientID %>');
      
      var ret = new Array(Number(txtfolioID.value),
                        txtfolioName.value);

      parent.returnValue = ret;
```

This parent.returnValue is not working at all. Please help

**EDIT**
I changed the code parent.returnValue to this

```
       var opener = window.opener;
                    if (opener) {
                        var oDom = opener.document;
                        var elem = oDom.getElementById("txtfolio");
                        if (elem) {
                            elem.value = 'Success';
                        }
                    }
```

Now the error **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document')** is gone but still it's not showing the child window value to parent window. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value from child window to parent window using window.open in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801374/how-to-return-value-from-child-window-to-parent-window-using-window-open-in-java)

Comment: @NolanCarpenter it didn't helped. Now I am getting this error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document'). What to do?

Comment: @Maximious are you waiting long enough for the element to actually exist?

Comment: @KevinB I don't understand your question. pls could you please clarify?

Comment: @Maximious In other words, where within your code does the problem begin. *"it's not showing the child window value to parent window."* is unclear, as it could be because `elem` is null and therefore doesn't exist yet, or because `opener` is null. or it could even be a CSS issue, for all we know.

Comment: @KevinB it's not css issue. If I write **opener.document.getElementById("txtPortfolio").value = "Success";** it throws uncaughttype null error that DOM is not ready and I'm trying to assign a value to it. So I changed it to **window.opener = true** then assign the value. Any clue to solve it?

Comment: @NolanCarpenter this link doesn't help me :-(

Comment: @KevinB I think you are right. <b>elem</b> and <b>opener</b> is null or doesn't exists yet.  How to solve it?